# Is it possible to record Quick Time video of iPhone that is rotating?

Tags: iphone, video, quicktime, screen-capture

I want to record a short video of the app I'm developing.

I'm using QuickTime and iPhone connected via lightning cable.

[image]

The moment I rotate my phone the recording stops.

Is it possible to record such a video?

---

Possible workaround: record my whole screen while preview of the iPhone is on.

Comment: Keep in mind my solution below will output a square shaped recording - but its the only way to encompass both a landscape and portrait recording in a single shot.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happens is because a video cannot change orientation mid-record.

> IE: My wife starts many of her video recordings on her phone in a
> vertical position. I remind her that we will likely have a terrible
> experience watching that video at a future date from a television
> because of the huge black bars on the left and right. She rotates it
> mid recording session, but all this does is make it so we have to turn
> our head on the couch.

There's a reason you haven't seen anything rotate on Youtube either -- it simply isn't equiped to all the sudden change from widescreen to portrait.

### **Solution**:

Quicktime (assuming you're on a mac based on your screenshot) also lets you select "New Screen Recording" from the File dropdown menu. You *could* record your whole screen like you alluded to, but if you want a more controled/correct size, you would do the following:

- Pretend like you're going to do a new iPhone recording. Have the phone on the screen. Take note of where the phone is on the screen in portrait mode, as well as landscape mode.
- Use sticky notes on your monitor to create a "square" that will make sure your phone is completely visible during landscape as well as portrait. (see where I'm going with this?)
- Tricky part. Open your applications folder. COPY quicktime to your desktop. Double click the desktop icon. This will open a SECOND instance of quicktime.
- Use the second instance of quicktime to do a "New Screen Recording". You do NOT have to record your whole screen; Select the square that you made with sticky notes on your monitor so we record this area.
- Hit record on the second instance of quicktime, while the first instance of quicktime is simply used to watch the phone in both portrait and landscape!

I know, it's a little involved. Likely easier to buy some software, but for free -- you can't beat it.